# My Python regular expression is not matching any data in my text file for YYYY date format

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning

I have a text file that contains dates in different formats. e.g.

2014

2015

January 7, 2015

6th January 2012

.

.

etc.

Now, I am trying to write a regular expression to print all the dates that are in YYYY format in the .txt file such as 2014, 2015.

However, I am not getting any matches from the code I executed. Could anyone please help with the problem ? Thanks.

My Python Code:

```
import re

for i in "file.txt":

    match = re.match(r'\d{2}-\d{2}-(\d{4})', i)

    print(match)
```

Current Output:

```
None

None

None

None

None

None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems: first, you have not actually opened the file. So, `for i in "file.txt"` actually returns the letters "f", "i", ... in each loop iteration. Second, your regular expression is looking for DD-MM-YYYY, which is not present in your sample file. Lastly, `match` is not a string that you can print. Instead, this code works:

```
import re
myfile = open("file.txt", "r")
for i in myfile:
    match = re.match(r'\d{4}$', i[:-1])
    print(match.string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried your solution, however, I am getting the following error message - 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'.

I then removed ".string" from print(match.string). The error message went away, but it still outputs multiple "None" text lines with no matches.

Comment: If you don't want to print the non-matching lines, you will have to add an `if` statement accordingly. Also, what version of python are you using? Looked like you are using python3, and `match.string` works fine on python 3.4.7. I just tried it, and it works fine on python 2.7.13 as well.

Comment: I have Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.6.3 with PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4. I tried the code on both but still get multiple "None" lines with no matches. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @user8929822 You may try `match = re.search(r'\d{4}', i[:-1])` (or with `(r'\b\d{4}\b'`), then print `match.group()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this peace of code.

dates.txt looks like this

```
2014
2015
January 7, 2015
6th January 2012
```

and here is the code to extract only year in YYYY format.

```
>>> f = open("/Users/kgowda/Desktop/my_work/play/dates.txt",'r')
>>> [re.search(r'\d{4}', x).group() for x in f.readlines() if x]
['2014', '2015', '2015', '2012']
```

If you want to remove duplicates, use `set`

```
>>> set([re.search(r'\d{4}', x).group() for x in f.readlines() if x])
set(['2015', '2014', '2012'])
```

If you text file contents like below

```
2014
2015
January 7, 2015
6th January 2012
0,2006 1,2007 2,2008 3,4 March 2014 4,"April 10, 2013" 5,7 August 2007
```

Use `findall` to get YYYY.

```
>>> [re.findall(r'\d{4}', x) for x in f.readlines() if x]
[['2014'], ['2015'], ['2015'], ['2012'], ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2014', '2013', '2007']]
```